# Computing length of graph on $[0,2]$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions

So say I have a function $f$ that's a linear function composed of two linear pieces and continuous on $[0, 2]$. I also know that $f(0) = f(2) = 0$ and that $\text{max}\,f = 1$.

My question is, how do I compute the length of the graph of $f$ on that interval?

Thank you dearly in advance.

Comment: By "composed of two linear pieces," what exactly do you mean? Running on the assumption it's a piecewise function, I don't *think* this is enough information to determine the length. Consider the value $x$ at which $f(x) = 1 = max(f)$. Then you can connect $(0,0)$ to $(x,1)$ with one line, and then to $(2,0)$ with another. This effectively makes a triangle, and if you do the algebra, the perimeter sans the base (the length of $f$) is $L = \sqrt{x^2 + 1} + \sqrt{x^2 - 4x + 5}$, i.e. dependent on where the function reaches it's maximum.

Comment: For the record, the "algebra" I refer to is basically that you can drop an altitude of the triangle down from $(x,1)$ to the $x$-axis, dividing the base into chunks of length $x$ (left) and $2-x$ (right). The altitude is perpendicular by definition, and you know it's length is $1$, so you can use the Pythagorean theorem to solve for the hypotenuses of the constructed right triangles (the length of each chunk of $f$). Since the full length is dependent on $x$, it doesn't have a specific length. For example, check the values of $L$ at $x = 1/2$ and $x = 1$.

Comment: $L(1) = 2 \sqrt{2}$ and $L(1/2) = \frac{\sqrt{5}+3\sqrt{3}}{2}$, obviously not equal. .... of course I now realize a potential oversight in that maybe you weren't looking for a "specific" length, e.g. "the length is 3" or whatever, as opposed to a formula. I guess it depends on what the question is aiming for? In any event, unless I overlooked something, you can only get, at best, a formula for the length, depending on where that maximum of $f$ is.

Comment: Also a final note. Assuming I'm right thus far, a nuance worth noting: $x$ must satisfy the inequality $0 < x < 2$. Otherwise, $f$ wouldn't be a function. (Graph it and consider the "vertical line" test and you'd see it.)

Comment: Actually scratch that; you could define a function with $x$ outside of $[0,2]$ - it just wouldn't be a triangle. If $x < 0$, then you have that line from $(x,1)$ to $(0,0)$, and then one from there to $(2,0)$. In this case, as should be clear, the length of $f$ is $2 + \sqrt{1+|x|^2}$. A similar argument follows for $x > 2$. $x = 0,2$ still won't generate functions though (vertical lines).